# How can I set an environment variable inside of a playbook, then use it inside of a lookup?

Tags: ansible

I'm working with `community.kubernetes.k8s`. When I use the module, I can set `K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG` as an environment variable inside of my playbook and it is respected by the module. When I use the `k8s` lookup, however, the environment variable isn't available inside of the lookup. Based on the documentation, this behavior is expected.

With this:

```yaml
- name: "My Playbook"
  environment:
    K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG: "{{ lookup('env', 'HOME') }}/cluster_config/kube_config.yaml"
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
```

This prints an empty string:

```yaml
    - name: Look up environment variable
      debug: msg="{{ lookup('env', 'K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG') }}"
```

This fails due to that empty string:

```yaml
    - name: Look for a namespace
      set_fact:
        namespace: >
          {{ lookup('community.kubernetes.k8s', 
                    api_version='v1', 
                    kind='Namespace', 
                    name='myNamespace') }}
```

This works as expected because the environment variable is available to the module:

```yaml
    - name: Create a namespace
      community.kubernetes.k8s:
        state: present
        resource_definition:
          apiVersion: v1
          kind: Namespace
          metadata:
            name: "{{ item }}"
```

I'm wondering whether there is a way to declare an environment variable inside of my playbook and have it accessible from inside of lookups? I don't want to set this in my bashrc or anything like that because I need different settings for different situations.

Alternatively, how would you suggest getting that value into the lookups?

Note that the `k8s` lookup does accept `kubeconfig` as an argument which is analogous to having `K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG` set as an environment variable. Is there a way for me to pass a variable to the `kubeconfig` argument like this?

```yaml
    - name: Look for a namespace
      set_fact:
        namespace: >
          {{ lookup('community.kubernetes.k8s', 
                    kubeconfig={{ my_kube_config }}, 
                    api_version='v1', 
                    kind='Namespace', 
                    name='myNamespace') }}
```

Comment: (a) there's nothing stopping you from setting `vars: { my_kube_config: "..." }` at the same time you set `environment:` in your playbook (b) those `environment:` values are present in `vars.environment` which is `list[dict]` so presumably: `kubeconfig={{ environment | selectattr("K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG") | map(attribute="K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG") | first }}` if you just wanted the environment: as the source of truth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html#setting-the-remote-environment) "*The environment: keyword does not affect Ansible itself, Ansible configuration settings, the environment for other users, or the execution of other plugins like lookups and filters*"

```
- name: "My Playbook"
  environment:
    K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG: "{{ lookup('env', 'HOME') }}/cluster_config/kube_config.yaml"
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:

    - shell: echo $K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG
      register: kubeconfig

    - name: Look up environment variable
      debug: msg="{{ kubeconfig.stdout }}"
```

The above playbook would result in following output:

```
PLAY [My Playbook] **************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [shell] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Look up environment variable] *********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "/home/ps/cluster_config/kube_config.yaml"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```